# Counting the use of another bot's commands

Tags: javascript, python, discord.js, discord.py, bots

I am using the DISBOARD site to promote a server.

I would like to count the number of bumps each user has so that I can reward them for their involvement. Is it possible to count the command usage of a given bot by a given user with a JS or Python bot?

I've tried to search for some already-existing bots that do this.

Comment: Not familiar with the bot, how do the commands work? If it's a message command (`!bump` or similar) you can have a bot read messages and detect those with the string "!bump". However, if it is interaction based, I don't think it's possible for a third-party to see these interactions.

Comment: you need to write !bump or use slash command /bump

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is possible in one of two ways, either check every message for the command, or setup a bot with the exact same command so when a bump is triggered, it triggers our bot too. I've gone with the second option below.

```py
@bot.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    user_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    with open('bump_counts.json', 'r') as f:
        counts = json.load(f)
    if user_id in counts:
        counts[user_id] += 1
    else:
        counts[user_id] = 1
    with open('bump_counts.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(counts, f)
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} has bumped {counts[user_id]} times!')
```

This code triggers a bump log and message whenever the `!bump` command is ran, however does not check if the DISBOARD bot actually replies, meaning people could spam it.

Make sure you create a file called `bump_counts.json` with `{}` inside it before trying to use this command; or use your own solution and or database.

You could use the [`bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) coroutine to check if a message is sent by DISBOARD and then check if that message was a successful bump, just add this logic to the bump command.